# What is the fix for java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get which comes while running a spark application to move data into HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, greenplum

I am trying to move data from GP to Hive using greenplum spark connector jar: greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar.
I read the table as below:

```
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Data_Read").set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "1200s").set("spark.network.timeout", "12000s").set("spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed", "true").set("spark.shuffle.compress", "true").set("spark.shuffle.spill.compress", "true").set("spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown", "true").set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer").set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "512m").set("spark.serializer", classOf[org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer].getName).set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true").set("spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead", "8192").set("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead", "8192").set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false").set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true").set("spark.sql.tungsten.enabled", "true").set("spark.executor.instances", "1").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g").set("spark.executor.cores", "1").set("spark.files.maxPartitionBytes", "268435468").set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "400")
  try {
    Class.forName("io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider").newInstance()
  }
  catch {
    case cnf: ClassNotFoundException =>
      println("No class def found. Killing the application...." + cnf.printStackTrace())
      System.exit(1)
    case e: Exception =>
      println("No class def found. Killing the application...." + e.printStackTrace())
      System.exit(1)
  }
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).master("yarn").enableHiveSupport().config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").getOrCreate()
  val yearDF = spark.read.format("io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider").option("url", "url").option("server.port","port").option("dbtable", "tablename").option("dbschema","schema").option("user", "userID").option("password", "12345678").option("partitionColumn","headers").option("partitions",64).load().where("period_year=2017 and period_num=12 and source_system_name='BANKERS'").select(splitSeq map col:_*).withColumn("delCol", lit(0))

  dataDF.write.format("csv").save("hdfs://location_of_the_file_on_HDFS")
```

I see that below queries are hitting GP as well.

```
INSERT INTO "schema"."spark_c04d88c2015291d9_38ee758b9192317b_driver_1016" 
(creation_date,attribute50,headers,attribute12,drill_line_pk_id,sap_partner_func_area,attribute38,global_attribute2,global_attribute4,usd_mor_activity_amount,attribute5,journal_line,drill_debug_info,reference_8,last_updated_by,sap_reference,document_type,attribute47,attribute48,last_update_tms,created_by_name) 
SELECT creation_date,attribute50,headers,attribute12,drill_line_pk_id,sap_partner_func_area,attribute38,global_attribute2,global_attribute4,usd_mor_activity_amount,attribute5,journal_line,drill_debug_info,reference_8,last_updated_by,sap_reference,document_type,attribute47,attribute48,last_update_tms,created_by_name 
FROM "schema"."table" WHERE ("period_year" IS NOT NULL AND "period_num" IS NOT NULL AND "period_num" = 12 AND "source_system_name" = 'BANKERS' AND "period_year" = 2017) 
AND (gp_segment_id = 48)
```

But the job runs for some time and without any proper result/progress, it ends with the exception: `java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get`. Full exception stack message can be seen below. There are 64 segments in our greenplum databases and hence it creates 64 tasks which can be seen below.

```
Exception Message:
[Stage 5:> (0 + 48) / 64]18/12/27 10:29:10 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 11, executor 11): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.jdbc.Jdbc$.copyTable(Jdbc.scala:43)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GreenplumRowIterator.liftedTree1$1(GreenplumRowIterator.scala:110)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GreenplumRowIterator.<init>(GreenplumRowIterator.scala:109)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRDD.compute(GreenplumRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Spark-submit used:

```
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 spark-submit --class com.partition.source.PartitionData --master=yarn --conf spark.ui.port=4090 --driver-class-path /home/devuser/jars/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar:/home/devuser/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar --conf spark.jars=/home/devuser/jars/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar,/home/devuser/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 13G --keytab /home/devuser/devuser.keytab --principal devuser@DEVENV.COM --files /usr/hdp/spark2-client/conf/hive-site.xml,testconnection.properties --name Splinter --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/devuser/jars/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar splinter_2.11-0.1.jar
```

The jar file: greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar uses gpfdist protocol. I am using the driver class mentioned in the greenplum pivotal [documentation](https://greenplum-spark.docs.pivotal.io/110/read_from_gpdb.html).
I tried to debug the issue as much as I can but I don't understand where is it going wrong.
Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here ?

Answer (score 0):

What version of greenplum are you using? Also, have you tried the latest version (v.1.6) of the GP Spark Connector? The latest version improves memory usage, and the way partitions are created.

I noticed that your DF uses the `partitions` option which was only introduced in version 1.6. The supported option in version 1.3 is `partitionsPerSegment` which defaults to 1. You can try a `partitionsPerSegment` value of 2 and see if there is any difference.

```scala
val yearDF = spark.read
.format("io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider")
...
.option("partitions", 64)
.load()...
```

Hopefully this information helps, please try my suggestion above or the latest version (1.6) of the Greenplum Spark Connector.

Comment: Ok. We are using GP version 4.3.16. I got couple of doubts. 1. Our GP Database has 64 segments. So will this: option("partitions", 64) apply for one segment each ?
2. Can I use both: partitions & partitionsPerSegment ?
3. What could be the reason for noSuchElement exception ? I have applied everything as per the documentation. It still seems strange to me why is the code breaking with no response.
I'll run the code with latest connector jar and keep you posted.

Comment: 1. option("partitions", 64) will be ignored by the GP Spark Connector
2. No, you have to use `partitionsPerSegment`. `partitions` will be ignored
3. I'm not sure, I have never seen that error before, but it would be interesting to find the root cause.
Please, keep us posted with any additional information you may be able to provide.